# Como pasar parametros por HTMLbegin Form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hola tengo el siguiente codigo

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("PDF", "Operaciones", FormMethod.Get, new { @target = "_Blank" }))
        {
            <button type="submit" id="btnImprimir" formaction="MovimientoPDFReport"  class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">
                <i class="fa fa-print"></i> Imprimir
            </button>
         
        }
```

> Pero quisiera enviarles estos dos parametros: Alguien sabra como puedo hacer?

```
 var tipo =  "?movimientoTipo=" + $("#cbocategoria").val();
 var movimiento = "&movimientoNumero=" + $("#txtNumero").val();
```

Comment: Enviarle los parámetros a quién? Al controlador? A la vista? Por la sintaxis, parece ASP.NET MVC, pero, cuál versión: MVC 4, MVC 5, MVC 6? Por favor, agrega detalles relevantes. "Pasar parámetros por HTMLbeginform" no nos dice nada.

Comment: @Arriel perdona la falta de información... Estoy utilizando MVC 5 y quisiera enviar esos dos parametros a ese controlador, te cuento... al dar click al boton me redirige a una pagina en blanco donde tengo un informe por REPORT VIEWER pero en ese controlador estoy pidiendo dos parametros... que son los que tengo que enviar...

Comment: @Arriel mi objetivo es pasar esos dos parametros por medio de HtmlBegin...

Comment: @Arriel me notifico que habias comentado algo?

Comment: Hola, "#cbocategoria" y "#txtNumero" lo tienes en otro form y los quieres cachar por medio de JQuery?

Comment: @AbrahamChan muchas gracias por tomar el tiempo y ayudarme... te comento... 1) Tengo una vista ej "Productos" ahi tengo #Cbocategoria y #txtnumero esos dos valores los quiero mandar a ese Controller "PDF","OPERACIONES" ahi yo los recibo: public FileResult MovimientoPDFReport(string movimientoTipo, string movimientoNumero) y esos dos valores lo que hacen es que se imprimen en una parte de mi reporte RDLC ReportViewer.

Comment: @AbrahamChan por lo que estoy haciendo de esa manera? antes lo tenia sin nada de HtmlBegin unicamente mi boton lo tenia enlazado con un Onclick y meti la Ulr del controller y los campos que te comente... pero no me abria el Reporte en una pestaña nueva... intente ponerlo en una etiqueta y la ppuse _blank pero lo que hacia era duplicar mi vista y en 1 pestaña estaba el reporte y en la otra mi vista pero en ella ya no podia interactuar con el sistema. Como que lo invertia

Comment: los campos "#cbocategoria" y "#txtNumero" los puedes poner dentro del Html.BeginForm para enviar los valores al momento de hacer el post, pero no se si por diseño o algo te impida hacer ese cambio.

Comment: o sabras alguna forma de que al darle click en mi boton me abra una pestaña nueva? aparte de mi vista principal?

Comment: Con jquery puedes abrir una nueva pesataña de la siguiente forma: `var redirectWindow = window.open(url, '_blank'); redirectWindow.location;`  en tu caso, si es un GET, puedes construir tu URL como: `MovimientoPDFReport?movimientoTipo=Dato1&movimientoNumero=dato2`

Comment: @AbrahamChan muchas gracias... despues de tantas vueltas, obtuve lo que queria... gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes enviar los parámetros para que se abran en una pantalla nueva, desde JQuery de la siguiente forma:

```
var redirectWindow = window.open(url, '_blank'); 
redirectWindow.location;
```

En tu caso, como manejas un metodo GET, puedes construir la URL como:

```
MovimientoPDFReport?movimientoTipo=Dato1&movimientoNumero=dato2
```

Comment: Con respecto a los comentarios te escribo la respuesta, creo puedes editar la pregunta para que se identifique tu necesidad original y pueda ser localizado por otras personas que tengan el mismo problema